# Induction. Am I missing something or is there a mistake in the question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k*3^k=\frac {3(3^n(2n-1)+1)} 4 $$

So let f(n)= $\sum_{k=1}^n k*3^k $

and  g(n)=$\frac {3(3^n(2n-1)+1)} 4$

By induction hypothesis, $f(n+1) = f(n) + (n+1)3^{n+1} \overset{\text{i.h.}}{=} g(n) + (n+1) 3^{n+1} = g(n+1).$

$$\frac{3(3^{n+1}(2n+1)+1)}4=(n+1)(3^{n+1})+\frac{3(3^n(2n-1)+1))}4 $$

I am stuck afterward, please help, thanks.

Comment: Looks like the question is stated correctly: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bk+3%5Ek,%7Bk,1,n%7D%5D

Comment: One thing you can do in such cases is to evaluate the sum for small values of $n$. You will find that the formula is correct for $n=1,2,3$. Of course this is not a proof, but it gives you confidence that there is no mistake in the question.

Comment: We do not have : 
 $g(n+1)=f(n+1)+g(n)$.  Please correct.

Comment: @stevielol  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

You need to be a bit more careful with your notation, since as you have defined the expressions, $f(n)$ is the entire sum, and $g(n)$ is the value of that entire sum; therefore, you should always have $$f(n) = g(n).$$

What you should be observing is that since $f(n)$ is composed of a finite sum of individual terms of the form $k \cdot 3^k$, the addition of another term of the form $(n+1)3^{n+1}$ to $f(n)$ should yield $g(n+1)$.  This is the induction hypothesis, and so it should be written $$f(n+1) = f(n) + (n+1)3^{n+1} \overset{\text{i.h.}}{=} g(n) + (n+1) 3^{n+1} = g(n+1).$$  The $\text{i.h.}$ over the equals sign is the step in the chain of equalities where the induction hypothesis is used. What you need to show is the rightmost equality in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate $$\frac{3^{n+2}(2n+1)-3-3^{n+1}(2n-1)-3}{4}=\frac{3^{n+1}(3(2n+1)-2n+1)}{4}=\frac{3^{n+1}(6n+3-2n+1)}{4}=\frac{3^{n+1}(6n+3-2n+1)}{4}=…$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k\cdot 3^k=(n+1)\cdot 3^{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot 3^k\stackrel{Ind. Hyp.}=(n+1)\cdot 3^{n+1}+\frac {3(3^n(2n-1)+1)} 4=$$
$$=\frac {4(n+1)\cdot 3^{n+1}+3^{n+1}(2n-1)+3} 4=\frac {3^{n+1}(6n+3)+3} 4=$$

$$=\frac {3(3^{n+1}(2(n+1)-1)+1)} 4=f(n+1)$$

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you get $$=\frac {4(n+1)\cdot 3^{n+1}+3^{n+1}(2n-1)+3} 4=\frac {3^{n+1}(6n+3)+3} 4$$ ?

Comment: Let $3^{n+1}=X$ then the numerator is $$4(n+1)X+X(2n-1)+3=4nX+4X+2nX-X+3=X(6n+3)+3$$

Comment: thank you man !

Comment: @stevielol You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

It's better, to prove this equals in another way.

$\sum_{k=1}^n k*3^k= \sum_{k=1}^n 3^k +  \sum_{k=2}^n 3^k +  \sum_{k=3}^n 3^k +... =  \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=i}^n 3^k $

Answer (score 0):

To do the inductive step, observe that:
$(n+1)3^{n+1}+\frac{3(3^n(2n-1)+1)}4=\frac{4(n+1)3^{n+1}+3(3^n(2n-1)+1)}4=\frac{(6n+3)3^{n+1}+3}4=\frac{3(2n+1)3^{n+1}+3}4=\frac{3(3^{n+1}(2(n+1)-1)+1)}4$...